# How to make object conversion more strict?

Tags: typescript

I have to convert an object to another object with different structure. What is correct way to do it?

I did the implementation but there are a lot of "any". And I guess type { [ key in keyof Partial ]: string } is not correct.

```
interface TestA {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: number;
  prop3: string;
  prop4: string;
}

interface TestB {
  key1: number;
  key2: string;
  key3: string;
  key4: string;
  key5 ? : string;
}

const testB2TestA: {
  [key in keyof Partial < TestA > ]: string
} = {
  prop1: "key2",
  prop2: "key1",
  prop3: "key3",
};

const testA: TestA = {} as TestA;
const testB: TestB = {
  key1: 1,
  key2: "A",
  key3: "B",
  key4: "C",
  key5: "D"
};


Object.keys(testB2TestA).forEach((key: string) => {
  (testA as any)[key] = (testB as any)[(testB2TestA as any)[key]];
});

console.log(testA);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.5.1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gILIN4BQyyADlAPYkCMAXMllKAOYDcRpFJATHSAK4BbAEbQ2xMpQDMdBszEdKAFhlhGIVgQC%20BAqEixEKdFgBChYgGsIAT1rJ%20w0eyvWe9VXOc3p7tRss2yr6eAdYArAD8Kn5s2gQI5CBYyJCmXMY4dHjIANrILsig%20TbkMMgACnBQYMBwADYAPBnYAHzIALrRzMiayAC8%20OwS1HQARC5cowA0Q5xu4zZU07NSYy6Sy5ps8YnJqZlomDj9%20L1wGIdY2GwJSWApRyZ0GSYn5sW2dFQzofPYy6EfKMTACPkFRgBhUEuMJjAAioy02wIAHkhAArCAIMAAOhcGAAFPsTOkjtgAJQ4mDkKAAUUQAAsCQSXF11OT%20m13kSychznyQNZyTkXO0TjzTHyLnBBcKJWASc0pQKhSKbO12rFydtbhhyHUIDi6uQmPKKdsgA)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're trying to achieve something I don't understand, just write a function that does the mapping, eg:

```
function testBToTestA(b: TestB): TestA {
    return {
        prop1: b.key2,
        prop2: b.key1,
        prop3: b.key3,
        prop4: b.key5 ?? ''
    }
}
```

The mapping between the different fields has to live somewhere so keep it simple.

Comment: Thank you for an answer but a pairs for object testB2TestA in some cases are stored in DB (and in some cases they might be hardcoded) so I have to iterate through the pairs.

Comment: @UserTest013 I don’t see how that matters. If you’ve got an object in memory you can reference the fields. Can you give a fuller example of why referencing the fields directly wouldn’t work?